# Changing File Name Based on User Input

Tags: python, automation, python-os, python-watchdog

I am trying to create a project that will allow the user to automatically sort their files in the downloads folder based on keywords in the file name. Part of this program is allowing the user to choose their file name, so that it may be sorted correctly. I am having trouble getting the user to be able to name their file when prompted.

````
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

import os
import json
import time

#Folders
folder_to_track = 'C:/Users/physi/Downloads'

image_destination = 'C:/Users/physi/Desktop/Images'

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    i = 1
    def on_modified(self, event): 
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            time.sleep(5)
            new_title = input("File Name: ")
            extension = str(input("Extension: "))
            new_name = folder_to_track + "/" + str(new_title + "." + extension)
            os.rename(folder_to_track + "/" + filename, new_name)
            time.sleep(2)
            print("File Renamed!")

            time.sleep(10)
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + new_name
            if 'Image' in new_name:
                new_destination = image_destination + "/" + new_name
                os.rename(src, new_destination)

event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()```
````

Above is the code that I have written, so far. When this code is run, it is able to detect when a new file is added to the Downloads folder, but as soon as it prompts the user to name their file, it prompts them with this error message...```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\physi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Users\physi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 203, in run
   self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
 File "C:\Users\physi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 376, in dispatch_events
   handler.dispatch(event)
 File "C:\Users\physi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 331, in dispatch
   {
 File "C:\Users\physi\Desktop\File_Management.py", line 33, in on_modified
   os.rename(filename, new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '37ea886b-25ed-4469-a13c-9c5fbf3ddd09.tmp' -> 'C:/Users/physi/Downloads/Hubble_Image..jfif'```
````

Could anyone help me to fix this program so it will allow the User to rename their file, then automatically save and sort it. Thanks, I appreciate the help!

*This code was inspired by Kalle Hallden's [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbW6FRbaSl0&t=237s%60%60%60)*

Answer (score 1):

I can see that in your code, you are not appending filename with the base directory name.

Your this line

```
os.rename(filename, new_name)
```

should be modified to

```
os.rename(folder_to_track+"/"+filename, new_name)
```

Comment: Appending the filename with the base directory name still reports out the same error, which is that it cannot find the file specified. Any ideas of why it cannot find this specified file?

Comment: can you update the code, so I can have a look if changes were correct

Comment: The code has been updated. I think my problem is that this program is reading the files as soon as they come into the downloads folder, which means that `filename` is storing the temporary name that acts as a placeholder for the file until it gets officially downloaded. I think I need to figure out a way to delay this program from reading the files in the Downloads folder, so that `filename` is not stored as the temporary placeholder name for the file. All of the temporary files have a .tmp extension and are then immediately replaced by the default name Download, once the file gets downloaded.